# D3 how to make dynamic sequential transitions work using transform/translate and offset coordinates?

Tags: d3.js, transform

I am trying to create an interactive org chart such that when I click on a box that box is repositioned in the centre of the SVG container and all other elements transition as well but remain in the same *relative* position. So if you click the top box in the list, they all move down together. Then if you click one of the lower boxes they all move up together but always so the selected box is in the centre. If you click on a box which is already in the middle it should not move but at the moment they are flying all over the place.

I have got this working for the first click but on each subsequent click the boxes start flying all over the place. I am using the mouse listener to get the current position and calculate an offset to centre the selected box that I feed into transform/translate. I think this is where the strange behaviour is coming from because the offset is calculating correctly (viewed through console.log) but the applied transition is not equal to this calculation.

I have read many posts about transform/translate but they all seem to apply to a single transition, not multiple sequential transitions. I have tried using .attr(transform, null) before each new transition but this didn't work. I have also tried to dynamically extract the current x,y of the selected component and then update these attributes with the offset value but this didn't work either. Am really stuck with this and any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
SD

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var cwidth = 1000;
var cheight = 500;
var bwidth = 100;
var bheight = 50;

// container definition
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width",cwidth)
                    .attr("height",cheight)
                    .on("mousemove", mousemove); 

// Background gray rectangle
svgContainer.append("svg:rect")
.attr("x",0)
.attr("y",0)
.attr("width",cwidth)
.attr("height",cheight)
.style("fill", "lightgrey");                                 

// data
var secondData = [
   { "idx": 1, "name": "Commercial" },
   { "idx": 2, "name": "Finance" },
   { "idx": 3, "name": "Operations" },
   { "idx": 4, "name": "Business Services" }
];

var secondElements = secondData.length;

// group definition
var secondNodes = svgContainer.append("g")
       .attr("class", "nodes")
       .selectAll("rect")
       .data(secondData)
       .enter()
       .append("g")
       .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
         d.x = 300;             
         d.y = ((cheight/secondElements)*d.idx)-bheight;
         return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; 
       });

// Add elements to the previously added g element.
secondNodes.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("height", bheight)
    .attr("width", bwidth)
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("y", function() {return -(bheight/2);})
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
    .on("mousedown", center);

// Add a text element to the previously added g element.
secondNodes.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "left")
    .attr("x", 15)
    .attr("y",5)
    .text(function(d) {return d.name;});

// gets current coordinates for transition 
var current = [0,0];
var xshift = 0;
var yshift = 0;

// get offset to centre from current mouse location
function mousemove() {
  //console.log(d3.mouse(this));
current = d3.mouse(this);
xshift = 500 - current[0];
yshift = 250 - current[1];
}

//applies transitions
function center(d) {

secondNodes.selectAll("rect")
    .transition()            
    .delay(0)            
    .duration(500)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xshift + "," + yshift + ")")
    .each("end", function() {
        secondNodes.selectAll("text")
            .transition()            
            .delay(0)            
            .duration(0)
            .attr("transform", null);   
    });

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything to keep its relative position, it seems to me that something far easier to do would be to include everything in a `g` element that you can set the transform attribute one. That is, instead of moving many elements, you would have to move just the top-level container. The code you have for handling clicks would remain pretty much the same except that you only need to set the transform attribute on that one element.